# How to create a web service which returns JSON rather than XML for GET and POST (no AJAX)?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, json, asmx

I would like to create a web service which returns results as JSON in ASP.NET with a HTTP GET and POST bindings.

In other words I would like a webservice which would return JSON if one types it's url in a browser. The XML representation is done automatically in NET 3.5.

I know I can use ScriptMethod (as shown below) to make ajax calls return JSON, but that is not what I'm after.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public SomeClass Example()
```

Comment: So what are you after exactly?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using WCF?

Comment: Re: Shiv: I want a rest API which can return JSON and XML depending on something (path or extra param in url).

Comment: Re: John: Because I could get XML with [WebMethod] and I don't know WCF. But you're right WCF is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you saying (If I understand you correctly), A Web Service uses SOAP, and JSON is not part of SOAP. JSON is it's own protocol. So you don't really want to use the Web Service framework?

If so then you can use a simple HttpHandler that returns some data in the form of JSON

Here is an example of this
http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2008/12/16/httphandler-json-data/

Comment: Shiv: Re: "A Web Service uses SOAP, and JSON is not part of SOAP". Yeah, but you get HTTP GET and HTTP POST for free with [WebMethod]. And of course I can write the output to the stream myself, but that's not really using the framework.

Comment: @John, well, I didn't say don't use it. The OP said he that's not what he's after so I provided another alternative.

Comment: @Tymek, well if you're looking for something out of the box then WCF is the way to do it. Using a Handler you can do all of that too. Very simple and you're using a framework. If you're looking for a REST framework (out of the box) then WCF is one option. If you're looking to support REST in your app without WCF then using just simple HttpHandlers is very simple and light weight. But until it's clear what it is you're after, I'm afraid I don't know what else to suggest. you keep saying you don't want something but don't really say what you're after :)

Comment: @Shiv: edit your answer to make this clear, and I'll remove the downvote (SO won't let me remove it until you edit).

Comment: @John, thanks, re-wrote my answer to make clear what I was saying.